# problem about equinumerosity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How we can prove that $R$ is equinumerous with $R^n , n>1$ ?  Of course we can define an injection from the set of real numbers to $R^n$ , but the inverse is the main problem i think in order to use the Schroder-Bernstein theorem.  Would be grateful for your helps and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know an injection $f:R^2 \to R$, you can use the same injection to get an injection $\rho:R^n \to R$.

Explicitly, $R^2$ injects into $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ via the map: $f(x,y) = \left((2/\pi \arctan(x)+1)/2,(2/\pi\arctan(y)+1)/2)\right)$. 
$(0,1)\times(0,1)$ injects into $(0,1)$ via $(0.a_1a_2\ldots ,0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots)\mapsto 0.a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots$

and $(0,1)$ injects into $R$ by the inclusion map $i$. The composition of these injections yields an injection from $R^2 $ into $R$. Call this injection $\psi_1$. Now use $\psi_1$ to get an injection from $R^n$ to $R$ via $\psi_{n+1}(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_{n+1}) = \psi_n(\psi_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n),a_{n+1})$. 
The details of proof that these underlying injections are indeed injections and that the recursion that defines $\psi_{n+1}$ defines an injection are left as an exercise.

Comment: Weirdly, I can't figure out the injection from $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$

Comment: Ah no. I see cantor's zig zag numbering to prove that that $\Bbb Q$ is equinumerous with $\Bbb N$ works here as well. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Im afraid as i have thought about it, but i couldn't reach something useful.

Comment: @Sabyasachi You can use arctan function to get an injection from $R^2$ into $(0,1)\times (0,1)$, and then use an injection from $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ into $(0,1)$ by a shuffling function. Then use a tangent to inject $(0,1)$ to $R$

Comment: @Rustyn ah that is brilliant. Although I am little partial towards using(abusing?) cantor's method.

Comment: @Aref to find an injection from $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ you can use either of the two methods presented here.

Comment: The identity is already an injection of $(0,1)$ into $\mathbb R$, Russ.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Ha. correct. Guess I was thinking in terms of bijection, oops